# Using Flyway not able to set variable for postgress

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Good Day!

PostgreSQL using flyway not able to create variable but using PostgreSQL client or command line its working well.

Below code is working well in client application [like DBeaver]

`@set TEST = 'testing by us';`

but when I add sql in flyway file its give error

`@set TEST = 'testing by us';`

> ---
>
> SQL State  : 42601 Error Code : 0 Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "@"   Position: 1
> Location   : db/migration/pgsql/_env/V1__zopn_obsolete.sql
> (C:\workspace\zara-flyway\target\classes\db\migration\pgsql_env\V1__zopn_obsolete.sql)
> Line       : 1 Statement  : @set TEST = 'testing by us'
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
> or near "@"

Comment: `@set` isn't a valid [SQL command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html). If it works in DBeaver, then this is something that DBeaver provides

Comment: Actually any sql working perfect with DBeaver or command prompt its working with flyway .sql files.

I check with both way 
1)set TEST1 = 'testing by us';
2)\set TEST1 'testing by us';

but its give error flyway

Comment: `\set` is a [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) command that only works within `psql`. I don't use Flyway, but I don't think it uses the `psql` command line client to run the script. So the only valid SQL commands you can use in a migration script are those [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)